# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$user' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)

Tags: php

I did a function that calculates the total price, by a specific user and his cart shopping, with PHP.

I`m getting this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$user' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) in C:\xampp\htdocs\myPrograms\projectTest.php on line 43.

This is my code (the problematic line is the 2nd line below):

```
    Class bill {

    $username= 'almog';

    echo "Your total price for this bought is:" .Total_bill($username). "Dollars"."<br>";

    function Total_bill($username) 
    {
        $total = 0;
        $query= $this-> db->query ("select serial_number, count_purchase, price_item from bought_history LEFT JOIN
        product ON bought_history. serial_number = product. serial_number where username=username and date_purchase= date_purchase");

    foreach($query as $key=> $value )
    {

        if ($bought_history. $serial_number->$count_purchase ==1)
        {
            $total = $total + $product. $serial_number->$price_item;
        }
        else 
        {
            $total = $total + ($product. $serial_number->$price_item * $bought_history. $serial_number->$count_purchase);
        }
    }

    return $total; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us what you've tried and share your code?

Comment: this is the db 


This is my DB: 
-- Table structure for table `bought_history`
--

CREATE TABLE `bought_history` (
  `username` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `serial_number` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date_purchase` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `count_purchase` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: You will need to update / edit your post with everything used in your project. Use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60179236/edit) button under your question to do that. @AlmogDavidof

Comment: updated my post

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> Class bill {
>
>     $username= 'almog';
>
>     echo "Your total price for this bought is:" .Total_bill($username). "Dollars"."<br>";
>
>     function Total_bill($username) 
>     {
> ```

You can't put "code" directly inside the class definition - which is what it looks like you are trying to do here. By "code" I'm refering to the `$username` variable assignment and the `echo` statement that follows. (Fix the `$username` parse error and you'll get the same parse error refering to the `echo` statement.)

However, it's not clear where that code should go (inside a class method OR called from outside the class OR not use a class at all?) since you are referencing the `Total_bill()` class *method* as a global function (which it is not in your example).

To get your code into a "working" state, either:

1. Move your "code" outside of the class definition entirely. For example:

   ```
   Class bill {

       // Class definition here...

   }

   $username = 'almog';

   $billInstance = new bill();

   echo "Your total price for this bought is:" .$billInstance->Total_bill($username). "Dollars"."<br>";
   ```
2. OR, move your code into another class method (although this probably doesn't make much sense given what you are trying to do). For example:

   ```
   Class bill()

       // Rest of class definition here...

       function outputTotalBill()
       {
           $username = 'almog';
           echo "Your total price for this bought is:" .$this->Total_bill($username). "Dollars"."<br>";
       }
   }

   $billInstance = new bill();

   $billInstance->outputTotalBill();
   ```
3. OR, perhaps you shouldn't be using a `class` here at all? And `Total_bill()` should be a global function in your example?

#### Reference:

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php